# Database-agnostic pagination for Ruby

Tags: ruby, pagination, sinatra, parse-platform

All Ruby pagination gems I've found end up depending on a specific type of storage/ORM (ex: ActiveRecord). What do I need to know to make some basic pagination for [parse-ruby-client](http://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client)?

parse-ruby-client queries look like this:

```
query = Parse::Query.new("Widget")
query.limit = 10
query.skip = 5
query.get
```

I'm using this with Sinatra and ERB templates.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine fully ORM-agnostic pagination gem, but most of popular Ruby ORM's are supported by [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari). Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks. The ORM that I maintain, parse-ruby-client, is not so popular, unfortunately. I think I'll cook up my own solution.